# unable to connect to mysql over ssh tunnel to virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, mysql, tunnel

my setup
host: win 7
guest : opensuse  [10.0.2.15]
Ports forwarded 80, 22 from 127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.15
Connection to VM using winscp with user@127.0.0.1:22 using public key authentication is working. I can access Apache as well by going to 127.0.0.1 on host machine.

I can't access mysql by using ssh tunnel. I am using heidisql. I have another remote machine which I am accessing via ssh tunnel and it is working fine with same configuration on that server.

I always get

"SQl Error(2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update: if I use putty to first open tunnel and forward port 3308 to 127.0.0.1:3306 and then use heidisql to connect via tcp/ip with port 3308, I am able to connect with same credentials. I guess it may be heidisql issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I solve it by increasing "plink.exe timeout" setting in ssh tunnel tab.

Comment: This helped me with the same problem with MySQL Workbench. Doubling all the TIMEOUT values in the Preferences -> SSH resolved the connection problem.